# In my code spacebar is not changing color on keypress but other keys are I am not sure what is the problem

Tags: javascript

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].setAttribute('keyname', buttons[i].innerText);
    buttons[i].setAttribute('lowerCaseName', buttons[i].innerText.toLowerCase());
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        if (e.key == buttons[i].getAttribute('keyname') || e.key == buttons[i].getAttribute('lowerCaseName')) {

            buttons[i].classList.add("pressed");
            setTimeout(function () {
                buttons[i].classList.remove("pressed");
            }, 100)

        }

    }
})
```

I was trying to change the background color of button on keypress but it's not working for space bar.
I have added here a EventListener for every button but its not working for space bar not sure what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do like this:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].setAttribute('keyname', buttons[i].innerText);
  buttons[i].setAttribute('lowerCaseName', buttons[i].innerText.toLowerCase());
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

  var key = "";
  if (e.which == 32)
    key = "Space";
  else
    key = e.key;
  // alert(e.keyCode);
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {


    if (key == buttons[i].getAttribute('keyname') || key == buttons[i].getAttribute('lowerCaseName')) {
      console.log(key)
      buttons[i].classList.add("pressed");
      setTimeout(function() {
        buttons[i].classList.remove("pressed");
      }, 100)

    }

  }
})
```

```css
.pressed {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button>e</button>
<button>f</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>Space</button>
```

Comment: What was the problem with the code in the question, how does your code solve that problem? How does your code work, what does it do? Try to explain your answers in order to teach OP, and future visitors, and avoid posting code-only answers where possible.

Comment: The spacebar is returning ```" "``` in ```e.key```.  According to @Ansh logic, he is storing the text in attribute and compare it with ```e.key```. That's why we can't add the class if ``we keypress the space. I solved this issue.

Comment: You're more than welcome, thank you for taking it constructively. But, and I'm sorry that there's a "but," please [edit] your question to include the explanation there, comments are transitory, prone to deletion, and people shouldn't have to read comments to understand the posted answer. :)